# What is a "cluster" in system architecture?

Tags: architecture, cluster-computing

I'm hoping to get a more specific search term for "clusters", so that I can do more research on this topic. Please excuse me if my understanding is wrong.

From what I have read, the internet uses "cluster" to describe two things:

1. Combine multiple machines into a single machine, combining their resources into one "super computer". An example is this [pi cluster](https://www.raspberrypi.com/tutorials/cluster-raspberry-pi-tutorial/).
2. Combining multiple instances of the same application to perform something. I've heard people consider placing instances of apps behind a load balancer as a "cluster". I've encountered "mongo clusters", "server clusters", "agent clusters". I've heard people call microservices "clusters".

My confusion lies in the fact that the former combines multiple machines into one, and the latter splits a single machine (i.e. containerization) into many, then "joins" them together again. Are these two types of "clusters" distinct? What keywords do I use to find more information for each type of "clusters"?

---

(Specific reasons for researching this topic)

My firm has an existing solution where a high-compute batch job is spread across a fleet of servers, creating some sort of "compute cluster". [Hashicorp's one million container challenge](https://www.hashicorp.com/c1m) seems to showcase something similar. Hashi has also quoted Citadel for asking if it is possible to rapidly spin up 40 million container instances, hinting at the same use case at a larger scale.

What I'm trying to learn is why these organizations don't combine all available compute to form a "super computer cluster" to run one job, but instead splits their handful of servers into more "container clusters" to run smaller pieces of the same job.

I'm familiar with the ideas of availability, redundancy and fault tolerance. I'm also somewhat understand "clustering" for networking purposes. But I fail to see how any of this factors into high-compute cluster workload.

(I know I lack the vocabulary to describe this phenomenon. I'm actively looking for material on this topic, but I can't find material that describes these two types of clustering. If you know what field this falls into, please direct me)